# How can I have my loop search for a value rather than a string of words?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that has both words and values in cells and I am trying to delete the rows that don’t have values in the cells. My code works now if all of the numbers are negative but if there are positive numbers then my code won’t work. How do I fix this?

```
Sub tval 
    Dim s As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    S=2
    LastRow= cells.find(“*”,[A1],,, xlByRows,xlPreviousRow).row
    Do until s>LastRow
    DoEvents
    If InStr(1,Cells(s,4), “-“) > 0 Then
        S=s+1
    Else
        Cells(s,4).EntireRow.Delete
        LastRow=LastRow -1
    End if 
Loop
End sub
```

Comment: If you post some example data, that would be helpful. Looking at your code, it seems you are doing too many hacks. Also, please specify where does your data start or end or how do you determine the end of data?

Comment: If you want to *keep* rows with just letters, no numbers, why not just loop through the characters in a cel, check `ISNUMERIC(character)` and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

When deleting rows, you should always start from the end.

```
Sub tval 
    Dim s As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For s= LastRow to 2 Step -1
          If Not IsNumeric(Cells(s,4)) then
                Cells(s,4).EntireRow.Delete
          End if 
    Next s
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rTextConstants As Range
    Dim rTextFormulas As Range
    Dim rCombined As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Exclude row 1 so that only text values found in rows 2+ are found
    With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count))
        On Error Resume Next    'prevent error if no cells found
        Set rTextConstants = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set rTextFormulas = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues)
        On Error GoTo 0         'remove on error resume next condition
    End With

    If Not rTextConstants Is Nothing Then Set rCombined = rTextConstants
    If Not rTextFormulas Is Nothing Then
        If rCombined Is Nothing Then Set rCombined = rTextFormulas Else Set rCombined = Union(rCombined, rTextFormulas)
    End If

    If Not rCombined Is Nothing Then
        rCombined.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "No cells containing text found in sheet '" & ws.Name & "'", , "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Much better thought through then mine! +1 Cause this is more elegant than a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a bit of a different approach:

Before:

[image]

Code:

```
Dim RNG1 As Range, RNG2 As Range

Option Explicit

Sub TestCase()

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set RNG1 = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If RNG1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Count <> RNG1.Cells.Count Then
        Set RNG2 = Application.Intersect(RNG1, RNG1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2))
        RNG2.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

After:

[image]

You'll need to change this around to suit your range obviously. It should be a good starting point nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `AutoFilter` to filter the numbers, and delete the visible cells to accomplish this task. The code accounts for a header row.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End With
```